# Is it better to have lot of interfaces or just one?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, coding-style

I have been working on this plugin system. I thought I passed design and started implementing. Now I wonder if I should revisit my design. my problem is the following:

Currently in my design I have:

1. An interface class `FileNameLoader` for loading the names of all the shared libraries my application needs to load. i.e. Load all files in a directory, Load all files specified in a XML file, Load all files user inputs, etc.
2. An Interface class `LibLoader` that actually loads the shared object. This class is only responsible for loading a shared object once its file name has been given. There are various ways one may need to load a shared lib. i.e. Use `RTLD_NOW`/`RTLD_LAZY`...., check if lib has been already loaded, etc.
3. An ABC `Plugin` which loads the functions I need from a handle to a library once that handle is supplied. There are so many ways this could change.
4. An interface class `PluginFactory` which creates `Plugin`s.
5. An ABC `PluginLoader` which is the mother class which manages everything.

Now, my problem is I feel that `FileNameLoader` and `LibLoader` can go inside `Plugin`. But this would mean that if someone wanted to just change `RTLD_NOW` to `RTLD_LAZY` he would have to change `Plugin` class. On the other hand, I feel that there are too many classes here. Please give some input. I can post the interface code if necessary. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

After giving this some thought, I have come to the conclusion that more interfaces is better (In my scenario at least). Suppose there are `x` implementations of `FileNameLoader`, `y` implementations of `LibLoader`, `z` implementations of `Plugin`. If I keep these classes separate, I have to write `x + y + z` implementation classes. Then I can combine them to get any functionality possible. On the other hand, if all these interfces were in `Plugin` class, I'd have to write `x*y*z` implementation classes to get all the possible functionalities which is larger than `x + y + z` given that there are at least 2 implementations for an interface. This is just one side of it. The other advantage is, the purpose of the interfaces are more clearer when there are more interfaces. At least that is what I think.

Comment: You aren't charged extra for having the extra classes. If all you ever do is wrap those classes and use them internally, you haven't lost anything and can remove later. If you find you actually need them later but don't have them, your redesign will be painful.

Comment: Having multiple interfaces, unless needed, defeats the purpose of having an interface .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My c++ projects generally consists of objects that implement one or more interfaces.

I have found that this approach has the following effects:

- Use of interfaces enforces your design.
- (my opinion only) ensures a better program design.
- Related functionality is grouped into interfaces.
- The compiler will let you know if your implementation of the interface is incomplete or incorrect (good for changes to interfaces).
- You can pass interface pointers around instead of entire objects.

Passing around interface pointers has the benefit that you're exposing only the functionality required to other objects.

COM employs the use of interfaces heavily, as its modular design is useful for IPC (inter process communication), promotes code reuse and enable backwards compatiblity.

Microsoft use COM extensively and base their OS and most important APIs (DirectX, DirectShow, etc.) on COM, for these reasons, and although it's hardly the most accessible technology, COM's not going away any time soon.

Will these aid your own program(s)?  Up to you.  If you're going to turn a lot of your code into COM objects, it's definitely the right approach.

The other good stuff you get with interfaces that I've mentioned - make your own judgement as to how useful they'll be to you.  Personally, I find interfaces indispensable.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the only time I provide more than one interface, it will be because I have two completely different kinds of clients (eg: clients and The Server). In that case, yes it is perfectly OK.

However, this statement worries me:

> I thought I passed design and started
>   implementing

That's old-fashioned [Waterfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model) thinking. You *never* are done designing. You will almost always have to do a fairly major redesign the first time a real client tries to use your class. Thereafter every now and then you'll discover edge cases of client use that require (or would greatly benifit by) an extra new call or two, or a slightly different approach to all the calls.

Comment: I can't decide on voting this up or down. I don't agree with the first, but I couldn't agree more with the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), which results in more, smaller interfaces.

> "Clients should not be forced to depend on interfaces that they do not use."

More detail on this principle is provided by this paper: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf

This is part of the Bob Martin's synergistic [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a golden rule. It'll depend on the scenario, and even then you may find in the future some assumptions have changed and you need to update it accordingly.

Personally I like the way you have it now. You can replace at the top level, or very specific pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Having the One Big Class That Does Everything is wrong.  So is having One Big Interface That Defines Everything.

Comment: One big interface that defines everything is a necessary evil sometimes - if you're writing a COM object and have to expose functionality to managed code, you must lump everything into the IDispatch interface.  But in principal, I totally agree with you!